# drop rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, drop

I want to keep only the rows in which the time is between the July 4 and May 24 of the same year, so I'm using this code :

```
def fix_time(data):
     12     data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'], format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
---> 13     indexNames = data[ (data['timestamp'] < '24-05-2021 00:00:00') & (data['timestamp'] > '05-07-2021 00:00:00') ].index
     14     data.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
     15     return data
```

But it doesn't work as I wanted: when I use `data['timestamp'].max()` I get `2021-09-30` and that's not be correct.

Comment: *but it doesn't work as I wanted* What is the problem with what you have tried so far? Also, it could be best if you could provide a sample input and the corresponding outup.

Comment: i explained that when i try data['timestamp'].max() i get 30-09 and not 05-07 ! that means the code is not working properly @AmirhosseinKiani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`between` works better for this:

```
def fix_time(data):
    data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'], format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return data[data['timestamp'].between('2021-05-07', '2021-05-24')]
```

Also, note that you **must** use the ISO format of dates when comparing dates in pandas, i.e., you have to write `2021-05-24 00:00:00` (yyyy-mm-dd) instead of `24-05-2021 00:00:00` (dd-mm-yyyy).

Comment: Too fast for me :)

Comment: Was going to answer the same thing based on what I have learned from you in you previous answers:) +1

Comment: Haha, I was kinda at leisure writing this answer...unsuspecting that 2 or 3 others were writing with me! lol :D